# Datadog Rum vs Logger

Tags: monitoring, web-frontend, datadog, error-logging

I am looking at FE logging/ monitoring guideline for my project, and I am having a difficult time seeing when and why someone would use the Datadog browser log collection and RUM browser monitoring

https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/javascript/

https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/

Would be great if someone could share how they use these 2 datadog logging systems to monitor their FE projects?